# snowflake copy with Parquet file - facing error when '\' is present in the data

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, escaping

I am using Azure data factory to copy data to Snowflake.  Data file is in Parquet format.  Some of the columns contain ''.  This is causing an error during the copy execution.

```
Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=ERROR [22000] Found character 'W' instead of field delimiter ','
```

Data sample:

```
Col1         Col2
WO68239\     WO68239\
\            WO12345
```

I tried these snowflake copy options which did not work.

```
ESCAPE_UNENCLOSED_FIELD = NONE
ESCAPE = \
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this problem?

Thanks,

Comment: Usually Parquet gets ingested into a VARIANT column, but here I am assuming there are some transformations first and then data looks more like a structured format (CSV). The default [FIELD_DELIMITER](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-table) for CSV is **,** so this means if you have a column with a value that contains a **,** it would need to be [ESCAPE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-table)d with a character that usually is not part of the column values.

Comment: Yes, data contains a backslash(\) at the end.  This backslash needs to be escaped or basically ignored and copied as is to the target.  The backslash is confusing the column delimiter.

Comment: Have you tried setting the FIELD_DELIMITER then to \ rather than default , ?

Comment: Yes, tried that.  With csv file, I also tried \t (tab delimiter).  That also did not work at the data has many text fields where users have used tab, new line, enter and \ characters.  Then I changed my out put to Parquet format.  The Parquet file is getting created properly.  Parquest is handling all the special characters.

Comment: However, when I try to copy the Parquet file using ADF and snowflake connector, the backslash is creating an issue.

Comment: Raised a ticket with Microsoft Support team and they applied a software fix at the backend.  My pipeline started working without any issues or any changes required at my end.  Looks like this was an azure data factory - snowflake connector bug fix at the azure subscription level.